# Game invitation dialog have an error

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

i want to send game request to my facebook friends.but when i am used **FBSDKGameRequestContent** then is show up an GameRequestDialog that is popup menu.
and my code is here..

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
// Look at FBSDKGameRequestContent for futher optional properties
FBSDKGameRequestDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc]init];
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.content = gameRequestContent;
gameRequestContent.message = @"Become a Ninja!!!";
gameRequestContent.title = @"NinjaPan";
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.content = gameRequestContent;
[dialog show];
```

and Dialog show error is

### Error:The Parameter app_id is required

plz help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your already have a valid token before sending that game request:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {

    FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
    ...
   FBSDKGameRequestDialog* dialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc] init];
   dialog.content = gameRequestContent;
   ...
   [dialog show];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is FB's example :

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
// Look at FBSDKGameRequestContent for futher optional properties
gameRequestContent.message = @"YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE";
gameRequestContent.title = @"OPTIONAL TITLE";

// Assuming self implements <FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate>
[FBSDKGameRequestDialog showWithContent:gameRequestContent delegate:self];

FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
gameRequestContent.message = @"Take this bomb to blast your way to victory!";
gameRequestContent.to = @[@"RECIPIENT_USER_ID"];
gameRequestContent.objectID = @"YOUR_OBJECT_ID";

// Assuming self implements <FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate>
[FBSDKGameRequestDialog showWithContent:gameRequestContent delegate:self];
```

Also documentation says : ...These examples assume the sender has already authenticated the app.

Thank you Hiren.

Comment: gameRequestContent.to  is used for the recepient's id whom we want to send the game request

Comment: when i set your my app id this error occur.........[__NSCFConstantString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc394c

Comment: @hiren--you are right..gameRequestContent.to..is used to recepient's id

Comment: RAMA, I update my answer please check and let me know if it's works for you.